# Bind vuex state to this in data()?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm upgrading vuex to 2.0 and was wondering if its possible use mapstate/getters before data gets initialized?

In Vuex 1.0, the vuex state would be mapped before data() did so I could just call `this` and then the state I wanted to access

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  vuex: {
    getters: {
      userSettings: ({ settings }) => settings.userSettings,
    }
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      sendEmails: this.userSettings.sendEmails
    }
  }
}
```

But in Vuex 2.0, I have to do `this.$store.state.settings.UserSettings.sendEmails`

```
import { mapGetters, mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
data: function () {
   return {
    sendEmails: this.$store.state.settings.UserSettings.sendEmails
   }
}
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    settings: "settings"
  })
}
```

Is there a way to have that state initialized before data()? I have multiple components that make use of the state in the data initialization and having to call `this.$store.state`? I realize I can do some destructuring but I was just wondering if I could avoid that.

Comment: `sendEmails` should be a computed property, you can eventually create a getter for it (in your store).

Comment: @soju can you explain why it must be a computed property?

Comment: Did you read this : https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components ?

Answer (score 7):

I would set `sendEmails` in `mounted`

```
import { mapGetters, mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
    data: function () {
       return {
        sendEmails: []
       }
    }

    computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
        settings: "settings"
      })
    },

    mounted: function() {
       if (this.settings.UserSettings){
          this.sendEmails = this.settings.UserSettings.sendEmails
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it the best way binding vuex state into local data, cause i'm still new in vue ?

Comment: The best way really depends on what you are trying to do and when/how your data is being loaded. Maybe you could ask a question?

Comment: cause i use mapgetter that's why i'm asking you, try searching in inet using mapgetter very little ?

Comment: The best way is relative to what you want to do. If this works for your needs than you are good. If you need more from it then there is probably a better way.